# Adding a number to an array menu driven

Tags: java

I have a question. I just started learning about arrays in java. I understand arrays and how they kinda work, pretty how much to store data. But here's my problem, I am trying to add an existing integer to the array by using a menu. But, I do not understand why my program doesn't seem to work.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArraySorting
{
public static void main(String[] args)
  {
     int option;
     int integer = 0;
     int optionOne;




     Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Please enter a non-negative integer: ");
     integer = kb.nextInt();


     while((integer < 0))
     {
        System.out.println("I am sorry that is not a non-negative integer.");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Please enter a non-negative integer: ");
        integer = kb.nextInt();
     }

     option = displayMenu(kb);

     while (option != 6)
     {
        switch (option)
        {
           case 1:
              optionOne();
              System.out.println("Done with Option 1. Please enter another option.");
              break;
           case 2:
              //optionTwo();
              System.out.println("Done with Option 2. Please enter another option.");
              break;
           case 3:
              //optionThree();
              System.out.println("Done with Option 3. Please enter another option.");
              break;
           case 4:
              //optionFour();
              System.out.println("Done with Option 4. Please enter another option.");
              break;
           case 5:
              //optionFive();
              System.out.println("Done with Option 5. Please enter another option.");
              break;
        }
            option = displayMenu(kb);
     }
     if (option == 6)
     {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Thank you. Have a nice day.");
     }
}

  private static int displayMenu(Scanner kb)
  {
     int option = 0;
     while (option != 1 && option != 2 && option != 3 && option != 4 && option !=5 && option !=6)
     {
        System.out.println("\t\t1. Add a number to the array\n\t\t2. Display the mean\n\t\t3. Display the median \n\t\t4. Print the array to the screen \n\t\t5. Print the array in reverse order \n\t\t6. Quit");
        option = kb.nextInt();

        if (!(option == 1 || option == 2 || option == 3 || option == 4 || option == 5 || option == 6))
           System.out.println("I am sorry that is an invalid choice. Please try again.");
     }
     return option;
  }



  private static int optionOne()
  {
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

     int[] numbers = new int[99];

     for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
           {
              System.out.println("Please enter number");
              numbers[i] = input.nextInt();
           }
    return numbers;       
 }



}
```

Comment: what is not working?  Help us to help you

Comment: @ScaryWombat it doesn't compile sorry

Answer (score 1):

The code is at fault.

The thing is your function optionOne should return an array of integers. You have set the return type as just a single integer.

One of those needs to be changes

If the array has to be returned, which I think is the case, then the function should look something like this.

```
 private static int[] optionOne()
  {
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

     int[] numbers = new int[99];

     for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
           {
              System.out.println("Please enter number");
              numbers[i] = input.nextInt();
           }
    return numbers;       
 }
```

Cheers.

Comment: thank you! but it seems to keep running, and doesn't stop and return the user to the menu?

Comment: You have made an array of 99 numbers and are traversing based on its length, hence, your code will ask for number 99 times...You'll have to change that.